# Taking a mean of two vectors in R

Tags: r

I would like to take the mean of the two vectors below and store the value in vector B2.  Note that I am trying to take the mean value by ROW.

When I use:

```
B2 <-mean(Macro$X1372C,Macro$X5244C)
```

I get the error: Error in mean.default(Macro$X1372C, Macro$X5244C) : 
  'trim' must be numeric of length one.  What code should I be using?

[image]

The mean vector would look like:

Mean

2.960409952

3.012362779

3.920078183

3.286110877

3.994996196

3.916488088

5.071798314

3.745693115

4.852409799

4.438490606

5.256816758

4.174125673

5.076089227

4.532386721

Comment: Will `apply(cbind(Macro$X1372C,Macro$X5244C), 1, mean)` do the work for you?

Comment: That does the trick.  Is there a simpler way to get this result by any chance?

Comment: why not simply (Macro$X1372C + Macro$X5244C) / 2 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `rowMeans()`, which produces a vector of the mean of several columns for each row. The input must be an array (i.e., matrix) or data frame.

The code you want is:

```
 B2 <-rowMeans(cbind(Macro$X1372C,Macro$X5244C))
```

`cbind()` puts the two vectors into an array.

Comment: No need for `cbind`- just `rowMeans(Macro[c("X1372C", "X5244C")])` will do it.

Comment: Totally right. I was imagining a scenario where the vectors were not part of a data frame, but if they are then what you posted is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
Reduce(`+`, Macro[c("X1372C", "X5244C")])/2
```